# Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't find my wireless adapter on VMware

Tags: wireless, adapter

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on VMware on my laptop(HP ENVY 17) but it doesn't find my wireless adapter.

Answer (score 3):

Go under VM menu, and make sure that the card is connected.  See image below.

[image]

I thought it was a given, since we're talking virtual, but here it goes:

VM software simulates all sorts of hardware devices.

Virtual machines, show just a wired connection. They don't know about, or care, what the actual physical connection is, wired or wifi. VMs on my main PC using wired Ethernet, and on my laptop using wifi show the identical icon in the Notification area, and behave identically.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find your **wireless** adapter within the virtual machine. It doesn't see your real hardware but only "virtual hardware" provided by the virtualization product.

So in a VMWare guest you will always find a wired network adapter and no wireless one.

Comment: Isn't there any way to find the real adapter?

Comment: @NavHam not within the virtual machine.

Comment: @NavHam if you really want your VM to see a wireless adapter (to carry out wireless specific tasks, like `aircrack` to retreive wireless keys), you'll need to purchase a USB wireless adapter; a VM can detect that.

Comment: @NavHam Instead of posting a "thank you" comment please accept one answer to mark the question as *solved*. Just click on the checkmark on the left side of the answer.